# Как изменять текст menu в popupmenu программно

Tags: android, android-xml

popupmenu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:id="@+id/menugroup1" >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu1"
            android:title="Урок 1"/> //хочу программно менять эти тексты
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu2"
            android:title="Урок 2"/> //хочу программно менять эти тексты
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu3"
            android:title="Урок 3"> //хочу программно менять эти тексты
        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu4"
            android:title="Урок 4"> //хочу программно менять эти тексты
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

MainActivity

```
private void showPopupMenu(final View v) {
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup);
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.menu1:
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Lessons.this, LearnWordsFamily.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                return true;
                            case R.id.menu2:
                                Intent intent2 = new Intent(Lessons.this, LearnWordsFamily.class);
                                startActivity(intent2);
                                finish();
                                return true;
                            case R.id.menu3:
                                return true;
                            case R.id.menu4:
                                return true;
                            default:
                                return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
        popupMenu.setOnDismissListener(new PopupMenu.OnDismissListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDismiss(PopupMenu menu) {
            }
        });
        popupMenu.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Примерно как-то так:

```
popup.getMenu().findItemById(R.id.ITEM_ID).text = "newText";
```